# Determining if linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^4$ is onto and/or one to one

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have this question that I'm struggling with

> Let $T(2,1,4) = (3,0,-3,6)$ and $T(1,-1,3) = (2,0,-2,4)$
> is $T$ onto and/or one to one?

I tried breaking down the vectors as a combination on  $\mathbb{R}^3$ standard basis like this
$$2T(1,0,0) + T (0,1,0) + 4T(0,0,1) = (3,0,-3,6)$$
$$T(1,0,0) - T (0,1,0) + 3T(0,0,1) = (2,0,-2,4)$$
to understand how $T$ looks like but i have no clue how to continue.

Comment: You have not defined a map $T:  \mathbb R^3\to \mathbb R^4$.  You just defined a map on a two dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: @lulu The OP didn't define a map. It says that a map $T:\Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^4$ is given with those values at those two points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint for the one-to-one part: note that
$$\frac{1}{3}T(2,1,4) = (1,0,-1,2)=\frac{1}{2}T(1,−1,3)$$
and recall that $T$ is linear.

Do you know any example of linear map from $\mathbb{R}^3$ onto $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Comment: therefore T is not one to one....i did not noticed that:)
can T be onto ?

Comment: It is not one-to one.  Do you know any example of linear map from $\mathbb{R}^3$ onto $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Comment: actually,not one that come to mind.

Comment: Recall that $3=\dim(\mathbb{R}^3)= \dim (\mbox{im} T)+\dim(\ker T)$.

Comment: meaning there is no way that dim(ImT)=R4 
thank you!

Comment: Exactly. Moreover, in this case, $T$ is not injective which means that  $\dim(\ker T)\geq 1$. Therefore $\dim (\mbox{im} T)\leq 2$.